# stack data structure in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Here I have C++ code to implement a stack `push()` and `pop()` using a linked list. I `delete` / `pop()` one data and it works fine, but I want to `pop()`/ `delete` many data items. Assume the data is `6 5 4 3 2 1`, and I want to delete `6 5 4 3`, what can I do to achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Structure of the Node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
    
// top pointer to keep track of the top of the stack
Node *top = NULL;

//Function to check if stack is empty or not
bool isempty()
{
    if (top == NULL){
        return true;
    } else {
    }
    return false;
}

void pushStack(int value){
    Node *ptr = new Node();
    ptr->data = value;
    ptr->next = top;
    top = ptr;      
}
        
//Function to delete an element from the stack
void pop ( )
{
    if ( isempty() )
        cout << "Stack is Empty";
    else
    {
        Node *ptr = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete(ptr);
    }
}
    
// Function to Display the stack
void displayStack()
{
    if ( isempty() )
        cout << "Stack is Empty";
    else
    {
        Node *temp = top;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    pushStack(1);
    pushStack(2);
    pushStack(3);
    pushStack(4);
    pushStack(5);
    pushStack(6);
      
    pop();
    displayStack();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  why should i call pop()  four times?

Comment: @willy Because that is what you asked for: "*I want to delete `6 5 4 3`*" Those are the last 4 numbers pushed on the stack, so it requires 4 calls to `pop()` to remove them.

Comment: I thought you had a linked list, and were confused on wrapping and constraining it to behave like a stack. Instead you are writing a linked list and just giving it a stack interface. I'm meh on which approach you should be using, that depends.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau    and what should i do if i want to delete the item between 6 and 3 ?

Comment: Now the comments make it sound like OP just wants a linked list and not a stack anyway.

Comment: @willy Then you would simply iterate through the list until you find a node that has the desired value, `delete` it from the list, and update the previous node's `next` pointer to point at the next node in the list. Repeat as needed. But, this is not how a stack is meant to work.

Comment: @sweenish  can you rewrite the codes?

Comment: If I did, it would look nothing like what you've presented. That's a C-style linked list. And depending on what the actual goal is, the rewrite might be nothing more than `#include <stack>`. But I'm guessing this is homework. So no, I won't write your homework for you.

Comment: @sweenish  how sould it supposed to be

Comment: @sweenish   for learning purpose only and expanding knowledge

Comment: An actual class for one. Preferably a template class, since a container should be capable of being a container regardless of the type of data it's holding. A stack class should really just be wrapping some other more generic container. If you did the hard work and wrote a linked list already, your stack class would hold a list privately, and the public API for the class ensures that the linked list only behaves like a stack.

Comment: I would suggest finding a better learning resource then, as your questions have so far indicated that you don't know what a stack is, and that's a problem if you're trying to write one.

Comment: @willy see the update I just made to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 items pushed on the stack, and you are asking to remove the last 4 items that were pushed.  Simply call `pop()` 4 times, eg:

```
int main()
{
    pushStack(1);
    pushStack(2);
    pushStack(3);
    pushStack(4);
    pushStack(5);
    pushStack(6);
      
    displayStack(); // displays "6 5 4 3 2 1"

    pop();
    pop();
    pop();
    pop();

    displayStack(); // displays "2 1"
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ljSsYl)

---

**UPDATE:**

In comments, you are asking how to remove specific nodes from the middle of the stack.  While that is easy to accomplish with a linked list, that is not how a stack is meant to operate. A stack is a First-In-Last-Out (FILO) container, meaning the first value pushed is the last value popped. So, you should only be pushing and popping values from the top of the stack, nowhere else.

But, if you really want to do this, it would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Structure of the Node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
    
// top pointer to keep track of the top of the stack
Node *top = NULL;

//Function to check if stack is empty or not
bool isEmpty()
{
    return (top == NULL);
}

//Function to add an element to the top of the stack
void pushStack(int value){
    Node *ptr = new Node();
    ptr->data = value;
    ptr->next = top;
    top = ptr;      
}
        
//Function to delete the top element from the stack
void pop()
{
    if ( isEmpty() )
        cout << "Stack is Empty\n";
    else
    {
        Node *ptr = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}
    
void removeValue(int value)
{
    if ( isEmpty() )
        cout << "Stack is Empty\n";
    else
    {
        Node *temp = top, **ptr = &top;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->data == value)
            {
                *ptr = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                return;
            }
            ptr = &(temp->next);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "Value not found\n";
    }
}

// Function to display the stack
void displayStack()
{
    if ( isEmpty() )
        cout << "Stack is Empty\n";
    else
    {
        Node *temp = top;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    pushStack(1);
    pushStack(2);
    pushStack(3);
    pushStack(4);
    pushStack(5);
    pushStack(6);
      
    displayStack(); // displays "6 5 4 3 2 1"

    removeValue(4);
    removeValue(5);

    displayStack(); // displays "6 3 2 1"
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/pEkAWW)

Comment: let me dive into